# Is the font in Messages.app changed in iOS5?

Tags: ui, ios

The fonts in the Messages app look much better in iOS5 than in iOS4, and wanted to confirm it. I couldn't find any discussion or note about this online. I don't have a phone running iOS4 around to compare myself.

Has it really changed? Any sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same font, but Apple added a very subtle text-shadow and tweaked the bubble reflection. That's the difference.

**iOS 4**
[image: iOS 4]

**iOS 5**
[image]

Comment: Yep, the text shadow was indeed what was causing the text to stand out. Thanks for the screen shots!

Comment: What a horrible message on iOS 5...